# in linux, does routing take different path on loopback vs IP assigned to NIC

Tags: linux, networking

I am using RHEL 6.3 (2.6.x kernel). I have tcp based client server applications. I noticed that when i run them on the same host, the throughput is approx the same, irrespective whether server binds to loopback or local IP assigned to NIC.

What is the reason behind it? My understanding is that loopback is software based routing, where as when local IP assigned to NIC is involved, the hardware is involved in the data path. Is that true?

Comment: It shouldn't be. The routing decision is made BEFORE the packet is sent to the driver stack. So if the decision is "send back to localhost", the hardware shouldn't be involved at all. (http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hardware does not get involved.

As soon as the routing function knows that the destination address is local, the packet is switched to ingress path. Which is incidentally why sniffers can't capture such packets, because that hook happens to be after the point of this decision.

Comment: well there are many sniffers that can capture such packets. tcp dump, ngrep all can capture packets on device `lo`.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im you would have to look in lo (if it supports sniffing), not the interface that has the local ip address in question. http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback